# How can I make portable Windows XP/7/8.1/10 flash drive?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-3

I have 64 GB 3.0 flash drive I just bought for any purposes First I wanna try to make NOT BOOTABLE, but PORTABLE flash drive. When I plug it into any PC, it opens directly Windows, without any installation. And when removing the flash drive, the PC will not has Windows again. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: A flash drive with a pre installation environment that doesn't need to be installed on a hard drive IS BOOTABLE

Comment: You want a *non-bootable* Windows install. That's an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the best: Even without doing anything, it automatically makes everything for 100% free:
http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/

Comment: this is a 3rd party tool to prepare a windows to go drive. i don't see why  should this  be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: It's answer, because it's which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Windows-To-Go does exactly what you need. Plug-in , boot up and voila it's your OS with your files.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go

Comment: there is also gandalf's WinPE environment..  I don't know if BartPE is still around and for win7

Comment: Windows to Go is bootable, they (for some reason) want a *non-bootable* Windows.